# Closure library key Event listen does not work

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I tried the below code to listen key events using google closure-library, but the code does not work.

```
goog.require('goog.events.EventHandler');
goog.require('goog.events.EventType');
goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.editor.Command');
goog.require('goog.editor.Field');
goog.require('goog.editor.Field.EventType');

-----------------------below--not worked------------------------------------------

var myField = new goog.editor.Field('editMe');

goog.events.listen(myField, goog.events.EventType.KEYPRESS,
         function(){alert('12')});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to listen the event on relevant DOM element:

```
goog.events.listen(myField.getElement(), goog.events.EventType.KEYPRESS, function(){alert('12')});
```